# What languages have a three-way vowel distinction with backness?

Tags: vowels, frontness-backness

I am learning a Tigrinya for the last couple of months, and find it difficult to grasp and produce the central vowels of the language (see picture). I want to know if there are other languages which have this three way distinction regarding backness, the only other language I found was Norwegian.

[image]

Comment: [English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf), for one. There's 4 nonlow front vowels and 4 nonlow back vowels, plus one central vowel (/ə/), which ranges all over the nonlow spectrum because there are no contrasts with it.

Comment: see Lindau's (1978) paper "[vowel features](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/dm/featgeom/lindau78-vowelfeatures.pdf)"

Answer (score 2):

In general, vowel backness (as well as all the other attributes) is not the property of a certain language. It's because of the nature of the human vocal tract.

This way, each vowel sound produced has a certain backness (as well as the other features).

However, languages use different *mappings* of phones to phonemes. In other words, each point on a vowel diagram is not a point, but rather an area. Everything that falls into that area is mapped to a certain phoneme.
There are plenty of languages that do not distinct backness (on IPA vowel diagram, it looks like an area occupying the whole width of the diagram).

For example:
Polish "m**y**sz" (mouse) `[mɘ̟ʂ]`. Different speakers may actually say `[mɪʂ]` or `[mʊʂ]`, but a listener would *map* it to an existing phoneme, `ɘ̟`.
German "bitt**e**" (please) `[ˈbɪ-tə]`
Greek "ακακί**α**" (acacia) `[ɐ-kɐ-ˈci.-ɐ]`

There is yet another consideration. Although some languages lack *cardinal* central vowels, those vowel appear *in a spoken language* due to various phonetic phenomenons (of course, individual for every language). For instance, it's a common effect of centralization/reduction of unstressed vowels in Russian:

"молоко" (milk) `[mə-ɫʌ-'kɔ]`
Note that this word contains three "o", the last one in stressed, and two unstressed ones are reduced in different ways.

"этот" (this) `[ˈɛ-tət]`
Note that `ɛ` (front mid) in this word, regardless of stress, is often pronounced `ɜ` (central mid).

Comment: Are you suggesting that all languages have contrasting  vowel backness? There are a number of languages that have been analysed as having no backness contrast, eg Arrernte.

Comment: Any language may be analyzed in many ways. Some of them use other features to mark contrasts, but that doesn't mean there are no phonetic back vowels -- merely that the analyst doesn't think backness is a very important feature in their analysis.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut: no, each vowel produced by any human in any language has a certain backness (as well as the other features). Different backness may or may not map to different cardinal vowels, as jlawler noticed.

Comment: @jlawler precisely, that's why I said *contrastive* backness.

Comment: @bytebuster certainly, but there's a difference between phonetic variation in backness and the need for *contrastive* backness in an analysis. I was merely seeking clarification as to whether you're claiming that all languages have contrastive backness. And this has little to do with cardinal vowels (which are *not* specific to each language)--these are just a set of convenient (but arbitrary) reference vowels.

Comment: You seem to be using "cardinal vowel" to mean some representative or underlying allophone of a vowel phoneme (which would only make sense in a specific language), but the page you link to explains it as a language-independent reference vowel. That makes your answer a bit confusing.

Comment: @dainichi You are right, thanks. Let me rephrase the answer.

Comment: I think you mean to say: 'Everything that falls into that area is mapped to a certain *phoneme*.'

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an list of languages, you're probably going to have to do some research yourself. I looked at WALS, but it doesn't seem to have a chapter specifically related to backness. But you could have a look at languages with many [vowel phonemes](http://wals.info/feature/2A?tg_format=map&v1=c00d&v2=cfff&v3=cd00)
The more vowels, the more likely that there's a 3-way backness distinction.

If you're looking for familiar vowel sounds to help you pronounce the Tigrinya vowels or other central vowels, I suggest you find the vowels on Wikipedia, which usually has a list of languages with a specific vowel. Scanning through that list might give you an idea of how the sound should be pronounced. E.g. start with
[close central rounded vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_central_rounded_vowel)
and jump to other central vowels using the IPA vowel chart.

Answer (score 0):

The realisation of Tigrinya vowels, especially the 'sixth-row' vowel (marked as central in your table) differs and depends on the environment.
Please do contact me though if you're still learning Tigrinya, let's share resources for this under-documented languages. cheers